# Doctrine2 Append record before fetched ones

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I fetch from table 'disability_types' all types (id, name). After this I need do prepend the resulting array with new record 'all' with id=-1. Then those records are used to fill multiple choice select. I do:

```
$disabilityType = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AldenBonBundle:DisabilityType")->findAll();
```

And I tried:

```
$item = new \Alden\BonBundle\Entity\DisabilityType();
$item->setAsAll();//set name and id
array_unshift($disabilityType, $item);
```

but this give me the error `Entities passed to the choice field must be managed`. After some researching I tried

```
$disabilityType = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->merge($item);
```

but this produce error `Entity was not found`.

How should I merge new $item into disabilityType ?

Comment: you want to prepend this for view only purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the array hydration, and thus operate on the arrays.

```
$query = $entityManager
             ->createQuery('SELECT d FROM AldenBonBundle\DisabilityType d');
$disabilityTypes = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Now the `$disabilityTypes` variable is an array and you can `array_unshift` and so forth.